# ImportError: no module named 'adafruit_mcp230xx'

Tags: i2c, adafruit

I have a Trinket M0 board and am learning how to communicate to an MCP23008 IC.  I went to this site https://learn.adafruit.com/using-mcp23008-mcp23017-with-circuitpython/python-circuitpython and entered the code shown below.

I am using Mu to write code and communicate with the Trinket M0 board.
It keeps giving me this error [ImportError: no module named 'adafruit_mcp230xx'] and the I2C communication does not work.
The 'Check' gives me a green thumbs up

The page says to load the following files but I can not find them using the library link provided.
When I search the library for the file it says 'File not found'

From the website:
For non-express boards like the Trinket M0 or Gemma M0, you'll need to manually install the necessary             libraries from the bundle:

adafruit_mcp230xx.mpy
adafruit_bus_device

These are the lib files I have on the Trinket M0:
i2c_device.mpy
mcp230xx.mpy
mcp23008.mpy

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

This is the code on the Trinket M0 that I am trying to run:

```
import board
import busio
from digitalio import Direction
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23008 import MCP23008

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp = MCP23008(i2c)
mcp = MCP23008(i2c, address=0x20)

pin0 = mcp.get_pin(0)
pin0.direction = Direction.OUTPUT

pin0.value = True  # GPIO0 / GPIOA0 to high logic level
pin0.value = False  # GPIO0 / GPIOA0 to low logic level
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

I realize that my most likely problem is that I don't have the correct library files.
I have scoured the internet but can not find the files that are listed in the example.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out my mistake.  I misunderstood the instructions.  I ended up installing the entire folder (adafruit_bus_device and the folder adafruit_mcp230xx) and placed it into the 'lib' folder.  Seems obvious now, but for some reason I was trying to enter specific files from each folder.  Obviously, I was missing one of the files from the folder.  I will figure out which ones are needed and which ones are not needed.